# How to make redirections cacheable in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, joomla-3.3.x, redirect, cache

I am confused.

> To speed up page load times for visitors of your site, remove as many
>   landing page redirections as possible, and make any required
>   redirections cacheable if possible.

**Does any one have an idea on how to do that in Joomla?**

For example, how can I cache this redirection

http://website.com/ is a permanent redirect to http://www.website.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can cache redirect via `.htaccess` example for redirect non-www to www

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`R=301` mean it will be cached.

If you have done this redirect and google page speed is still throwing you an error, you need to ignore it and live with it ;p

Answer (score 2):

You can use sh404sef extension to improve sef and perfomance of your site. Cache, 301 redirections, ...

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef